# Is there a one word synonym for 'road condition'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Specifically about road surface being wet, icy or damaged - transport related.

If there's no one word synonym, then shorter expression might help too.

Comment: No language I am familiar with has a way of expressing this in a single word. Please clarify why you think English is different. And why it needs to be one word in the first place. Why not two. Why not seven. What is wrong with seven. Why does it have to be shorter. It's really very short already. Why are you not looking for a way to make it much longer. Thank you.

Comment: This might be described as "Conditions were icy". I've retagged your question: please do [have a look at the help](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: Hi @RegDwigнt, I'll have to use it as a prefix for many fields in an electronic form (e.g. RoadConditionDescription). I'm not native speaker, so I'm always aware there might be words I don't know or one's I might not find, unless I know what I'm looking for. I do believe you, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Road state

I suggest ‘Road state’, *state* being ‘the particular condition that someone or something is in at a specific time‘ - as I think this is a bit clearer than ‘road condition’.

Road state is the state of the actual road.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/state

Road state is also a tiny bit shorter than ‘condition’.

Comment: But OP specifically asks for (and tags for) a _single word_. 'Road state' is far less idiomatic than 'road conditions'. I will have to downvote next time I return.

Comment: Op is creating an electronic form with fields. (See comments)  In my view, ‘road state’ is clearer than ‘conditions’ which might be taken to include ‘traffic’. And op also says ‘If there's no one word synonym, then shorter expression might help too.’  Because, as stated in his comment, the phrase is going to be used repeatedly as a field identifier like ‘RoadConditionDescription’ and ‘state’ is already 4 characters shorter.

Comment: I won't downvote, though I think the question unsuitable for ELU, and this sort of answer hardly in line with 'a site intended for linguists' – OP could be expected to look for synonyms of 'conditions' themself. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=road+state%2Croad+conditions&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Croad%20state%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Croad%20conditions%3B%2Cc0) indicate how useful this answer is likely to be to many other visitors (an important thing to bear in mind on ELU).

Comment: I notice quite a lot of software programmers (often non-native speakers) looking for terms that will make sense to their users.

Comment: Hi @Jelila, this is a great alternative, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Filcuk glad if it helped!